# Identifying unknown map projection for image

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I intend to georeference and create a shapefile for some of the features but I'm unable to determine the correct map projection. (Working in QGIS ideally.)

The image is from a scientific study but the map projection is unknown. Does anyone have an insight about this map projection?

[image]

Comment: Dig in the direction of the conic projection, try to identify the main parallels ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's one way to find a similar CRS to the one used for an existing map**. Since your map has lat/long lines, you can make a GIS project with the same lines into different CRS's until you find one where the lines are curved and angled the same as in the image.

1. Create lat/long lines:

   - Use the grid tool to make a lat/long grid for this area (longitudes 23 E to 48 E, latitudes 32 N to 45 N) in EPSG:4326 (WGS84 unprojected).
   - `Densify` the grid, so it has lots of vertices. This way when you project it into another CRS, the latitude lines will appear curved.
2. Optional: add a vector layer of country boundaries for the area of interest.

   - Eg, get a worldwide layer from [Natural Earth Data](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/), select the countries in the area of interest, and export them to a new layer.
3. Change the project CRS until you find a CRS where the grid lines are curved similarly to the ones in your map image. As [@Cyril](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/120129/cyril) suggested, start with the conic projections. When you select a CRS in the CRS selector window, notice that the Extent is displayed below. Try to find one with an similar extent to your map.

   [image]

Keep in mind that you don't have to find *exactly* the right CRS. A reasonably similar CRS will give you reasonably good results when you georeference the image. And you can always re-run the georeferencer if you're not happy with the results.

Tip: when you georeference the image, save the georeference control points (GCP) in case you want to re-run the georeferencer.

[image]

Comment: These are very helpful instructions. I was able to find a projection which I am pretty happy with the result. Many thanks.